# Varnish cache only homepage first

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4, varnish-3

I am new to varnish cache.i have a website xyz.com and i want cache homepage first only so how to start with varnish and how will the vcl file look like for homepage cache only.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some basic VCL code that will cache the homepage explicitly and rely on  [the built-in VCL behavior](https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-builtin-vcl/) for all other requests.

```
vcl 4.1;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if((req.method == "GET" || req.method == "HEAD") && req.url == "/") {
        return(hash);
    }
}
```